# Problems Querying nested lists in RavenDB

Tags: c#, ravendb

I want to use RavenDB for a project I am doing, but before I can, I need figure out how to query nested objects...  Let me explain
I have a class like this:

```
public class Customer
{
 public string Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public IList<Orders> { get; set; }
}
```

Then the Order class:

```
public class Order
{
 public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
 public decimal OrderAmount { get; set; }
 public bool CustomerBilled { get; set; }
}
```

I create a bunch of fake data and add it to Raven -- some Customers have orders with only CustomerBilled set to true, some with CustomerBilled set to false, and some a mix of true and false on CustomerBilled.

What I need help with, is figuring out how to extract a list of Customers that 1 or more Orders with CustomerBilled set to false.

How would I create a query to do it?  I can't seem to get one to work, and I have no idea how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [dynamic queries](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/using-linq-to-query-ravendb) in RavenDB can handle this, I think the following should do what you want (sorry I can't compile the code right now to verify)

```
// List of objects - linq
from doc in Customers
where doc.Orders.Any( order => order.CustomeBilled == false)
select doc;
```

Edit: on the new link, scroll half way down to the section "more filtering options"

Comment: Great, that worked - I just had to change it slightly to some thing like this:   var item = from doc in session.Query<Customers>()
                   where doc.Orders.Any(y => y.CustomerBilled== false)
                   select doc;

Comment: Oh yeah, I wrote the plain text index, not the actual LINQ query. Glad you got it working

Comment: Your "dynamic queries" link now leads to a "page not found" message on the RavenDB site.